# 回答が、「回答でない」とはどういうことですか？

Tags: 討議, サポート, よくある質問の案, 回答でない

「回答でない」の理由での通報や削除投票についての説明、ないしどういったときに行うべきかの投稿がまだなかったと思うので、ひとまず meta.stackexchange のものを翻訳・投稿しています。

参考: [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/185073/301070)

- 回答が「回答でない」とはどういうことですか？
- どういうときに、「回答でない」として、通報ないし回答に削除投票したらよいですか？
- どういうときに、「回答でない」として、通報ないし回答に削除投票をしてはいけないでしょうか？
- 「回答でない」か自信はないけれども、削除すべきだと思う回答がある

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 「回答でない」通報や「回答でない」削除投票は何のためにありますか？

両方とも、回答投稿が、質問に回答しようとしていないので、削除する必要があることを示すモデレーション行動です。

- 通報: モデレーターに対して、回答投稿を削除する必要があることを通知します。
- 削除投票・削除を推奨: 主に「低品質な投稿」レビューを通じて、回答の削除を投票・推薦します。

### どういうときに、「回答でない」として、通報ないし回答に削除投票したらよいですか？

回答投稿が、以下のような用途で用いられた場合です。

- 新しい質問をしている
- 質問についての明確化を行おうとしている。
- 他のユーザーに対する返事・質問などを行っている
- 「ありがとう」や、その質問に対する別の回答投稿がうまくいったことの報告をしている。
- 質問のバンプアップを行っている。 (質問を空更新してタイムラインの上に持ってくること。)
- 質問に対する部分回答ですらない

### どういうときに、「回答でない」として、通報ないし回答に削除投票をしてはいけないでしょうか？

以下の場合は、「回答でない」には該当しません。

- 部分的に質問に回答している。 (質問が広すぎてすべての回答が部分的な回答になってしまう場合は、質問自体をクローズすべきです。)
- 回答しようとしているが、間違っていたり、技術的に不正確であったり、賛成できないと感じられる。(マイナス投票をするべきです)

### 「回答でない」か自信はないけれども、削除すべきだと思う回答投稿がある

「その他」理由でモデレーター通報を行い、どうしてその質問を削除するべきだと思うのかを説明してください。

Comment: 質問に対する回答に対して、第三者が回答の形で補足している場合を時々見かけます(今例を挙げろと言われると困りますが)。
回答に対するコメントでは書きづらいと感じて回答の形にしているのだと思います。
こういうものについても、回答として認めるor通報or削除投票orその他、どうすべきか書いた方がよいかと思います。

Comment: @masm 回答投稿に対するコメントが妥当な場面において、別回答として投稿している場合、主に新規ユーザーによるものが多いかと思います。そのような場合、例えば私が対応するとして、その別回答の内容に応じて、対応方法が変わりそうだ、と思っています。なので、まだ自分の中でも、「これが妥当そうである」と思うガイドラインがまだない状態なので、具体的なそのような投稿があれば、それをメタに投稿していただき、別スレッドで議論するのがよいのかな、と思っている状態です。