# StackOverflow How To: 回答のしかた

Tags: 討議, サポート, よくある質問の案, 回答の仕方

## 0. 目的

スタックオーバーフローで、新規ユーザーが回答者として参加したくなったときに、知っておいた方が良い事柄を整理する

## 1. 回答したい質問を見つける

#### 1.1 質問を検索する

- タグ: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/tags
- 未回答: https://ja.stackoverflow.com/unanswered

などから、自分が回答できそうな質問を探しましょう。

#### 1.2 タグをフォローする

トップページの「お気に入りのタグ」から、フォローするタグを整理できます。フォローしたタグについての新規投稿は、自分の「プロフィール」 -> 設定 -> 質問の購読 から、メールで通知を受け取ることができます。

## 2. 回答を書く

- 回答でない回答投稿は控えるようにしましょう。 参考: [回答が、「回答でない」とはどういうことですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2565/%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%8C-%E5%9B%9E%E7%AD%94%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84-%E3%81%A8%E3%81%AF%E3%81%A9%E3%81%86%E3%81%84%E3%81%86%E3%81%93%E3%81%A8%E3%81%A7%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B)

## 3. Be Nice

- https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice

Comment: 参考: [質問・回答・投票の仕方、まとめ](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1979/19110)