# 「自己解決した」ということ以外の情報がない、承認済みの自己回答は、回答投稿として適格?

Tags: 討議, 回答でない

今現在、 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/40209/754 この回答投稿に対して、「回答でない」の通報が寄せられています。回答投稿は、質問投稿者によってなされていて、内容は、「状況が変わり、自己解決した」とのことです。そして、なにを、どうやったか、などの問題解決のための情報は、含まれていない状態です。

この回答投稿は、通常であれば「回答でない」として削除対象だと思われるのですが、今回は以下の点が特殊だと思っています。

- 当該回答投稿が、質問者自身によってなされていて、かつ承認されている。 (自己承認回答)

このような場合において、この回答投稿の削除は、そもそも適切なのかそうでないのかについて判断に迷っています。

- そのままでよい?
- 削除されるべき?

  - (もしくは、コメントに変換されるべき?)

参考: [回答が、「回答でない」とはどういうことですか？](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2565/754)

Comment: `ツールのバージョンを上げた`、`他のツールと競合していた`などだと書きやすいですが、
チームの他メンバーが直したり、保留にしていて忘れた頃に見たら直っていたなどで、
そもそも原因が分からない(何時の間にか直っていた)場合って、どう誘導すればいいんでしょうね？
質問者も正解が分からなくなってるので回答ついてないなら質問を削除とかしてもらう？

Comment: @Myaku なんとなく、クローズあたりが妥当なのではないかと思うのですが、なんとなくなので、議論の余地があると思います。

Comment: そうですね。多分、質問者本人は「もう解決したから原因は分からなくてもいいや」とか考えてそうですし…、それなら追求して欲しいところではあるのですが、バージョン管理してるならコミット追ってもらうとか…でも1年近く前だしなぁ…

Answer (score 4, accepted):

件の回答が「回答でない」ことは確かだと思います。しかしご指摘のとおり、この "回答" を削除してしまうと何か有用な情報が消えてしまうようにも思います。

そこで、数日待っても未だこの状況なのであれば、回答をモデレーター権限でコメントに変換し、更に (現在 cubick さんが[して下さっている](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/23510/webpack%E3%81%A7%E3%81%AEtweenmax-easepack%E3%81%AE%E4%BD%BF%E3%81%84%E6%96%B9-typescript%E3%82%92%E4%BD%BF%E7%94%A8/40209#comment40814_40209)ように) 具体的な情報を求める補助コメントを入れるのは如何でしょうか。

ただ、もしかすると件の回答は「昔は駄目だったが現在のバージョンでは直っている」という意味かもしれないので、そこは慎重に判断が必要でしょう。数日待って様子見するのが良いように思います。

Comment: 当該回答投稿を、コメントに変換いたしました。